# Z-index of map objects

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios, cartodb, carto-mobile

Is it possible to specify Z-index of map objects in Carto Mobile SDK?
I am creating some objects on the map, but I can't control its z-index. I understood that the more closer to bottom object is situated the more closer to user it is displayed (z-index bigger). However, do we have ability to specify it manually?

Problem is in the popup I want to show to user. It is displayed under all map markers.

Xamarin.iOS is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Billboards like Popups and Markers you can set placement priority to larger than 0 (which is the default). This is given in Style level, via StyleBuilder:

```
BalloonPopupStyleBuilder builder = new BalloonPopupStyleBuilder();
builder.PlacementPriority = 1;
```